# How can I list subversion's runtime configuration options?

Tags: subversion

Say I want to know the value of the `global-ignores` option. How can I find it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~/.subversion/config
```

You can also change it there.

Edit: For clarity, that's a text file, not a program.

Comment: The option could also be set in the global config. I wondered if there was a simpler solution (e.g. using a client). Thanks anyway